Where does Alembic commit while using transactional DDL?
I need to create a check constraint without fully locking the table. According to postgresql documentation, this is achievable if it's done in two stages.
However, from reading the documentation I believe that I must ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT ... NOT VALID in a separate transaction to ALTER TABLE foo VALIDATE CONSTRAINT. Assuming I understand correctly, this is the only way for a concurrent transaction to insert data (checking the new constraint) in parallel with another transaction validating historic data.
Discussed here:

Normally, this form will cause a scan of the table to verify that all existing rows in the table satisfy the new constraint. But if the NOT VALID option is used, this potentially-lengthy scan is skipped. The constraint will still be enforced against subsequent inserts or updates (that is, they'll fail unless there is a matching row in the referenced table, in the case of foreign keys, or they'll fail unless the new row matches the specified check condition). But the database will not assume that the constraint holds for all rows in the table, until it is validated by using the VALIDATE CONSTRAINT option.


Question:
How do I ensure the alembic migration will commit between ADD CONSTRAINT and VALIDATE CONSTRAINT?
Is this as simple as putting the two statements in separate "versions". IE: does alembic commit every version. Or is there something else I need to do.
I don't really want to run without transactional DDL, that creates a high risk of making a very big mess in a mission critical database.

Should that not be ADD CONSTRAINT [...] NOT VALID and then VALIDATE CONSTRAINT?

Same applies to your second reference to the commands.

@AdrianKlaver not so much. I think the context is clear by that point


Other then: a)  VALIDATE CONSTRAINT has no meaning for ADD CONSTRAINT and b) Running in separate transactions is not necessary for that case. 2) From Alembic: Full support for transactional DDL. The default scripts ensure that all migrations occur within a transaction - for those databases which support this (Postgresql, Microsoft SQL Server), migrations can be tested with no need to manually undo changes upon failure.. I would try a small test case to confirm.


@AdrianKlaver alembic is heavily configurable. I can do a simple test case for my configuration, but not determine if that configuration is easily tweaked to fit my use case.

"does alembic commit every version" - With PostgreSQL (for which Alembic will assume transactional DDL) the default is to run all migration steps in one big transaction. However, setting transaction_per_migration=True will run and commit each step (migration script) in a separate transaction.
